# Left-align YAML title for Rmarkdown PDF

Tags: markdown, knitr, r-markdown

R gurus,

I wonder if it is possible at all to left align PDF output title in YAML in Rmarkdown documents.

And also is it possible to add a logo above title (in header)?

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: false

#title: "Multi pricing report"
latex_engine: xelatex
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
# spacing: double
endnote: no
---
```

You time and effort to answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `titling` package and add `\begin{flushleft}` before the title and `\end{flushleft}` afterwards:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: false
    keep_tex: yes
title: "Multi pricing report"
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}
---
```

Comment: I lost the original size of the title when i aligned left. Any reason why?

Comment: Not sure why, but you can solve it by adding `\LARGE` after `\begin{flushleft}`. So `- \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE}`